# Australian Bureau of Statistics shapefiles do not permit editing of the attribute table

Tags: population

Australian Bureau of Statistics shapefiles do not permit editing of the attribute table. I wanted to produce a small map with suburbs and population data about people over 65. I tried all sorts of round abouts but no success. Are there shapefiles from other sources that dont just copy ABS shapefiles?